# Não consigo fazer o botão de fechar janela do Pygame funcionar

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Estou aprendendo a usar as funções do Pygame, mas fiquei travado nesse problema. Eu criei uma janela com o Pygame, e depois fiz esse código para quando eu clicar no botão de sair a janela fecha-se.

***Código***

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
        print(event)
    # Atualizando a tela
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Não consigo entender porque ele não funciona, o programa durante a execução não mostra nenhum erro, mas quando clico no botão de fechar, nada acontece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta colocar `pygame.display.quit()` antes do `pygame.quit()`, já fora do loop.

Já vi pessoas que só conseguiram fazer dar certo colocando `exit()` depois, mas so tenta isso se a primeira opção não der certo.

Answer (score 2):

isso é fácil de resolver, basta usar a função nativa exit, cujo objetivo é fechar o programa

o pygame.quit() é para resolver um bug do pygame e deve sempre ser chamado antes do fechamento

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type==QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
      exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue um código básico para complementar a resposta do Henrique Seta.

Neste exemplo o `while` será executado enquanto `sair` for igual a `False`.

Note que dentro do `for` se o evento `QUIT` for capturado a variável `sair` será definida como `True` encerrando o loop para fechar programa como o `pygame.quit()`.

```
import pygame

def main():        
    pygame.init()
    tela = pygame.display.set_mode([300,300])
    pygame.display.set_caption("Iniciando com Pygame")    
    cor = (255,255,255) # cor branca
    sair = False

    while sair != True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sair = True               

            tela.fill(cor) # preenche a tela com a cor branca    

            pygame.display.update() 

    pygame.quit()

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

O problema é bem simples. você colocou o loop como sendo "True". sendo assim, não há parâmetro para que ele se encerre e ele roda infinitamente.

Você deve criar uma variável e atribuir o valor true a ela, dai então você coloca

while variavel:
e lá no código você coloca que, se o evento for "quit" a variável recebe false

continuar = True

while continuar:
for event in pygame.event.get():
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
continuar = False
print(event)
# Atualizando a tela
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use o sys.exit no ***if event.type == pygame.QUIT:*** isso evita o erro no terminal após fechar a janela

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).